# How do I extract data from mysql database to my charts.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, chart.js

I have no idea how to extract my desired data from my database. I have looked up online and the only ways that i have seen people do it is by using ajax or json codes. Is there anyway to avoid using that? Currently, my chart is hardcoded but i need the data to be extracted from the database.

```
 <script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            },
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
            }
        ]

    }

window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
}


</script>
```

Comment: Well you have to decide for some transport mechanism/format to get the data to the client since it can not get the data from the database directly, unless you are running on NodeJs or something the like. REST/Ajax/JSON is only one option but probably the most used and easiest to get started.

Comment: Hi are there any codes that i could use for the ajax/json codes?

Comment: You should probably look into different Javascript frameworks like https://angularjs.org/ or https://jquery.com/. They all provide their own abstractions for ajax/REST requests. It also depends on how you access the database on the server-side.